# converting OpenCV not working with Python-for-android

Tags: opencv, kivy, buildozer

I have a pretty solidly-functioning Kivy app, written in python and using the OpenCV2 library. having gotten it working on my laptop (windows) I then tried to convert it into an android APK using the python-for-android VM. after some issues (including adding more space to the VM and installing OpenCV on it) I managed to compile the APK successfully.

however, when running the app on android, the opencv part doesn't seem to be working. the kivy menus and such work fine, but loading the video - the job that opencv handles - simply doesn't happen. I'm going to try and connect the android device to the VM directly in order to try and get some debug information, but for now, can anyone think of any reasons why I might be having these issues?

thanks.

Comment: does the app crash when trying to do the openCV stuff?

Comment: @Juggernaut - not quite. it crashes when trying to use the expected output from the openCV part. as far as I can tell, openCV simply isn't opening the video correctly.

Comment: use `adb logcat` to see the raised exception. `adb` is in /.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-${version}/platform-tools

Comment: I don't seem to have an android sdk folder in .buildozer/android/platform

Comment: whee is your sdk then?

Comment: ah, no, I found it.

however, I've been looking over the build logs, and it seems that some of the numpy or scipy (which are opencv dependancies) dependancies aren't showing up properly, so I'm gonna try and get all those working.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV can work with camera on Android starting from version 4.5.2. Recipe 'opencv' in python-for-android v2023.02.10 uses version 4.5.1.

For more info look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69445715